# Perl searching for string contained in array

Tags: perl

I have an array with the following values:

```
push @fruitArray, "apple|0";
push @fruitArray, "apple|1";
push @fruitArray, "pear|0";
push @fruitArray, "pear|0";
```

I want to find out if the string "apple" exists in this array (ignoring the "|0" "|1")

I am using:

```
$fruit = 'apple';
if( $fruit ~~ @fruitArray ){ print "I found apple"; }
```

Which isn't working.

Comment: First, smartmatch in perl 5 is experimental and should generally be avoided. Second, when applied to an array, it looks for an exact match, so it won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I - like *@Borodin* suggests, too - would simply use `grep()`:

```
$fruit = 'apple';
if (grep(/^\Q$fruit\E\|/, @fruitArray)) { print "I found apple"; }
```

which outputs:

```
I found apple
```

- `\Q...\E` converts your string into a regex pattern.
- Looking for the `|` prevents finding a fruit whose name starts with the name of the fruit for which you are looking.

Simple and effective... :-)

**Update**: to remove elements from array:

```
$fruit = 'apple';
@fruitsArrayWithoutApples = grep ! /^\Q$fruit\E|/, @fruitArray;
```

Comment: This is great thanks. instead of {print "I found apple";} how would i remove all elements containing "apple" from @fruitArray

Comment: Updated my answer to remove all elements containing "apple" from @fruitArray

Comment: @MarcoS: I'm wondering why you chose to post this in the first place, as even from the first draft it's clear that you're aware that you're rewriting my own solution

Comment: Sometimes two answers with the same solution may contain different details and approaches which may result useful for OP to better grasp the solution... If you don't agree I will remove my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Don't use smart matching. It never worked properly for a number of reasons and it is now marked as *experimental*

In this case you can use `grep` instead, together with an appropriate regex pattern

This program tests every element of `@fruitArray` to see if it starts with the letters in `$fruit` followed by a pipe character `|`. `grep` returns the number of elements that matched the pattern, which is a *true* value if at least one matched

```
my @fruitArray = qw/ apple|0 apple|1 pear|0 pear|0 /;

my $fruit = 'apple';

print "I found $fruit\n" if grep /^$fruit\|/, @fruitArray;
```

#### output

```
I found apple
```

Comment: Adjust the regex according to what you're really looking for; this one assumes that the string has to start with `apple|`, not just contain `apple` anywhere.

Comment: @MarkReed: It assumes the target of the search is stored in `$fruit`, in the same way as the OP's own code. It's not the regex pattern that should be adjusted

Comment: Yes, but it requires the string to *start* with the contents of `$fruit` followed by a `|` symbol, which was my point.  It's not clear from the question that such restrictions are intended, although they make no difference with the sample data provided.

Comment: @MarkReed: That's fine. Either you've edited your comment or I misread it on my first take

Comment: More recent perls (>= 5.19.5) ship a List::Util >= 1.33 with the [`any`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any) sub, which functions like a short-circuiting boolean `grep`.  Plain `grep` will inspect every element of the array, which may be slow in rare cases (very big arrays, e.g.)

Comment: @pilcrow: I considered mentioning that, but the data would have to be extravagant for such a change to make any difference. Even then it would less than double the speed of what is presumably a tiny part of the whole program, and become completely irrelevant if there is any disk IO involved. Optimisation should never be done preemptively or blind, as the programmer's time is *by far* the most expensive

Answer (score 1):

If your Perl is not ancient, you can use the `first` subroutine from the `List::Util` module (which became a core module at Perl 5.8) to do the check efficiently:

```
use List::Util qw{ first };

my $first_fruit = first { /\Q$fruit\E/ } @fruitArray;

if ( defined $first_fruit ) { print "I found $fruit\n"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to the [smartmatch sun without melting your wings](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/rethinking-smart-matching.html) by using [`match::simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple):

```
use match::simple;

my @fruits = qw/apple|0 apple|1 pear|0 pear|0/;
$fruit = qr/apple/ ;

say "found $fruit" if $fruit |M| \@fruits ;
```

There's also a `match()` function if the infix `[M]` doesn't read well.

I like the way `match::simple` does *almost* everything I expected from `~~` without any surprising complexity. If you're fluent in perl it probably isn't something you'd see as necessary, but - especially with `match()` - code can be made pleasantly readable ... at the cost of imposing the use of references, *etc*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `grep`, that will loop the entire array, even if it finds what you are looking for in the first index, so it is inefficient.

this will return true if it finds the substring 'apple', then return and not finish iterating through the rest of the array

```
#takes a reference to the array as the first parameter
sub find_apple{
    @array_input = @{$_[0]};
    foreach $fruit (@array_input){
        if (index($fruit, 'apple') != -1){
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```